# "An hour" or "a hour"

Tags: word-choice, articles, pronunciation, indefinite-article, euphony

Which indefinite article should precede *hour* — *a* or *an*?

> - an hour
> - a hour

Does the usage of *an* vs *a* depend on the pronunciation — *a history*, *a hobby*, but *an hour*, *an honor*?

Answer (score 62, accepted):

> Does the usage of *an* vs *a* depend on the pronunciation: *a history, a hobby*, but *an hour, an honor.*

Yes. If a word begins with a vowel sound, then the correct article is *an*; otherwise, if it begins with a consonantal sound, the correct article is *a*.

Because *hour* is typically pronounced with a silent *h*, *an hour* is correct.

I wrote [a blog post about *an* vs *a*](http://english.blogoverflow.com/2011/11/articles-a-vs-an/) on the EL&U blog some time ago, and it covers a wide variety of other cases that you might be interested in.

Answer (score 19):

*An hour* is correct, because "hour" begins with a vowel sound.  *A* vs. *an* depends on pronunciation, not spelling.

Some notable cases:

- A/an NIC (network interface card)--proper spelling depends on prounuciation... *"A nick"* vs. *"an N-I-C"*
- A/an herb.  *"An erb"* in [many cases/regions](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/herb).  *"a herb"* (with pronounced H) in some

Comment: Have you got a reference for saying that 'erb' is more common than 'herb'? :)

Comment: @curiousdannii: http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/herb

Comment: According to [Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/herb#Pronunciation) "US pronunciation of the word varies; some speakers include the h-sound and others omit it, with the h-less pronunciation being the more common. Individual speakers are consistent in their choice, but the choice does not appear to be correlated with any regional, socioeconomic, or educational distinctions." This is surprising! I'm still not sure if "most regions" is accurate, but it doesn't matter.

Answer (score 2):

You are correct in your assumption. The usage does depend on the pronunciation. If the subsequent word starts with a **vowel** sound, then the previous word must be **an**. If the word starts with a **consonant** sound, then the previous word is **a**.