# an/a R function

Tags: grammar, articles, indefinite-article

R is a computer language ([link](https://www.r-project.org/)). When describing a function written in R, I want to know which of `an R function` or `a R function` is correct. I initially thought `an R function` was correct according to the conventional rule (e.g., [link](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/328/an-hour-or-a-hour)), but Google search shows that substantially more people use `a R function`. So I thought a special rule may apply here.

Comment: It's important to note that many people just use the "wrong" rule that it's based on the *spelling* being consonants vs vowels when it's actually about consonant vs vowel sounds, so a large number of "a R function" is likely to be just an error on their part rather than the actually correct way of writing it.

Comment: Your methodology is flawed.  Google Search is not a corpus and the result estimates are not result counts; Google has never attempted to make the estimates particularly accurate.  If you check [an actual corpus](https://corpus.byu.edu/iweb/?c=iweb&q=67170661) you'll find that *an* is more common, as expected.  Nothing to see here.

Comment: "Google search shows that substantially more people use a R function" needs to be substantiated with some data to validate your claim.

Comment: Remember, Google searches bring up webpages and blogs written by amateur authors who may be more careless than accomplished. Moreover, many of your "a R function" hits are false positives, like: _The A/R function has a strong..._