# A undershirt or an undershirt?

Tags: articles, pronunciation

I know the a/an rule, but as I meet both in my readings, I tried to google it, and I find both, with not site or dictionaries telling us we should use the one or the other one.

My question is: are they both common and accepted? Are they exceptions?

Comment: I don't know where you have found 'a undershirt', but it's incorrect. Words beginning with a vowel take 'an'.

Comment: For all practical purposes, the ***only*** thing that affects the ***a / an*** choice is *whether the word starts with a **vowel sound*** (it's irrelevant whether the *written* form starts with a "vowel" or "consonant" ***letter***).

Comment: Related: [“An hour” or “a hour”](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/328/36187)

Comment: @FumbleFingersReinstateMonica I know the a/an rule , but I'm not an English speaker, so it's hard to assess the sound it makes.

Comment: If you don't know how an English word is pronounced, you can find this in almost any dictionary. As you may know, for *centuries*, archaeologists / scholars were unable to decipher Egyptian hieroglyphs - *because they thought each glyph had **inherent meaning***. They only finally cracked the code when it dawned on someone that each glyph represented a ***sound***, not a ***concept***. That's my way of pointing out that ***real language is spoken*** - so if you really want to learn English you should pay more attention to how it's spoken than to how it's written.

Comment: I don't speak (is that the right word?) any sign languages, but does your "real language is spoken" still work for them?

Comment: @RichardWard For sign language it would be "real language is signed(?)" as opposed to written, and the point still holds: reading signs probably isn't a good way to learn sign language.

Comment: @KateBunting - 'unicorn' begins with a vowel! Come on. Could that be ***an*** useless comment?

Comment: @Tim Well, all right, words beginning with a vowel _sound_, as Fumblefingers says!

Comment: @KateBunting - still not exactly correct! A E, O and I have two sound choices at the beginnings of words. All are preceded by 'an'. U is odd... Correct me if I'm wrong - please.

Comment: @Tim We all learned 'a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u' and sometimes 'y'.  The sometimes 'y' is because 'y' can be a vowel e.g. as in 'sky' or a consonant e.g. as in 'yellow'.  Really, we should probably learn 'a', 'e', 'i', 'o', usually 'u', and sometimes 'y'.  'u' can act as a  the consonant-vowel combo 'you' as in 'unicorn' (younicorn), user (youser) or 'populate' (popyoulate).

Comment: @JimmyJames - I'm trying to understand the relevance of your comment.

Comment: @Tim "U is odd... Correct me if I'm wrong - please." looks like a request for clarification to me.

Comment: @JimmyJames - maybe, but where does Y come in?  We never use 'an' before a word beginning with Y.

Comment: @Tim Exactly.  Well, [almost](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/427820/words-starting-with-vowel-y).

Comment: @Tim: **an** Ypres woman left **an** hour ago.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

The correct article to use is ***an*** undershirt

> [image]

[Google Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=a%20undershirt%2C%20an%20undershirt&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ca%20undershirt%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Can%20undershirt%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Ca%20undershirt%3B%2Cc1%3B.t1%3B%2Can%20undershirt%3B%2Cc1) confirms

The American English term, *undershirt*, begins with a vowel *sound*
/ʌndərʃɜrt/ ([Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/undershirt)) and /ˈʌndəʃəːt/ ([Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/undershirt)), and words beginning with a vowel sound take "an".

Comment: The pronunciation you have given at the end appears to be a British English pronunciation, not American English.

Comment: @EricWofsey https://www.lexico.com/definition/undershirt but some American speakers pronounce the letter *r*, aka as rhotic  /r/  in "under" https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/undershirt. This has no influencer over the indefinite article.

Comment: Some American dialects are non-rhotic but the "standard" and most common American prounciation is rhotic.  Your first dictionary appears to exclusively display RP pronunciations and thus is not a source of information about American English pronunciation.  Of course you are right that this is irrelevant to the indefinite article, I just worry that some learners may get confused by your last sentence and think that you are giving the standard American English pronunciation.

Comment: @EricWofsey that's interesting.  I live in the Southern US, and do actually pronounce it "**un*duhshirt".

Comment: @RonJohn yeah, but unless you're secretly from Boston, you probably pronounce the "ir" part of the word with an actual "r" sound, and not just with the vowel in "eugh" on its own, as in non-rhotic dialects...

Comment: @Muzer well, I sure don't say "pahk the cah" or go to Hahvd.   It's very subtle.

Comment: @Muzer I noticed during a press conference about the Boston Marathon bomb incident that Bostonians save up the "r"s they remove from those words and add some of them to words like "law" in "law enforcement" (lawr enfahcement?), sort of like how Brits might refer to "Americer".  There must be some kind of Conservation of R Law(r) at work here.

Comment: @MontyHarder yes, it's called "intrusive r". Basically because in non-rhotic dialects, words like "car" don't have an "r" pronounced unless another vowel follows ("car engine"), but also because pronounciation rules based entirely on spelling are hard to memorise, the pronunciation rule for many dialects shifted from "pronounce the r in vowel + r + vowel" to "pronounce an r between (certain vowel sounds typically followed by r in spelling) + vowel". Because "law" sounds the same as "lore" in many non-rhotic dialects (mine at least) the rule applies to this vowel.

Comment: @MontyHarder - It's so we don't have jarring glottal stops. "Law [glottal stop] enforcement" sounds horrible. "Lawrenforcement" allows the sentence to flow.

Answer (score 56):

My favorite example is

> An uninformed man
>   A uniformed man (a you-knee-formed man).

You use *an* if the next word sounds like it starts with a vowel, *a* if the next word sounds like it starts with a consonant.

There are cases where there is no universal agreement about pronunciation. Some people say "a hotel" (a hoe-tell), some say "an hotel" (an oh-tell).

When abbreviations are written down, some people will read them aloud as the letters in the abbreviation, and some will read them aloud as words. NDA is read as "en-dee-aye" or "non-disclosure agreement"; you use *an* or *a* depending on how you read it.

Comment: Even better is "a unionised workforce" vs "an unionised gas" (-ized if you prefer)

Comment: ("a you-nyan-ized workforce" vs "an un-eye-oh-nized gas")

Comment: @AakashM Oh man it took me a while to figure out you meant un-ionised gas

Comment: "A unicorn let the maiden pet it."

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/103411/discussion-on-answer-by-gnasher729-a-undershirt-or-an-undershirt).