# a lb or an lb, which is right?

Tags: indefinite-article

> At just two weeks old, he weighs less than a lb.

or

> At just two weeks old, he weighs less than an lb.

Grammar Checker says "an lb" is right, really?

Comment: This does not answer your question, but if you wanted to avoid the doubt, you could use 'one lb'.

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["An hour" or "a hour"](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/328/an-hour-or-a-hour)

Comment: The abbreviation **lb** is read as (**a**) ***pound***, not (**an**) ***l-b***. The grammar checker is succeeding according to its own interpretation, but failing in the actual context.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wouldn't generally use the abbreviation in a sentence. The letters "lb" are a *unit* and are used with a number.  So it is valid to write "1 lb" or "5 m" or "1.4 kg", but you shouldn't write "I'll have a lb of apples". nor would you say "I'll have an ell-bee of apples."

Your grammar checker (and mine) is getting confused by this.  It is spotting the error, (a followed by "ell-bee") but it isn't giving you the right solution (change lb to pound)

So the correct spelling should be:

> At just two weeks old, he weighs less than a pound.

It is still correct to use the unit with a number:

> At just two weeks old, he weighs less than 1 lb.

Comment: +1 for this: _you shouldn't write "I'll have a lb of apples". nor would you say "I'll have an ell-bee of apples."_

Comment: Good point. I mean, I could see it in a handwritten journal, but "real" writing wouldn't use it this way.

Answer (score 2):

A general [rule-of-thumb](https://grammarist.com/usage/a-or-an/):

> When the following word begins with a vowel sound, the correct indefinite article to use is an.

In this case, *p* (from the word *pound*) is not a vowel sound so, therefore, *a* is correct.

My grammar checker also says *an* is correct, this must be a mistake with the grammar checker.

Comment: It would be "an", *only* if you actually pronounced the letters "l" and "b". The vowel rule should be based on what you pronounce, not necessarily what the written letter is... but since what you would pronounce is "pound", and that also begins with a consonant, it's still *a*.

Comment: Shouldn’t it be pronounced /el/?

Comment: @MicahCowan edited post

Comment: @CulverKwan see above

Comment: @CulverKwan 'Lb' is the traditional written abbreviation for 'pound' (weight),  from the Latin _libra_. When you read it out loud, you would say 'pound'.